# What does the following sed statement mean

Tags: sed

```
sed 's/<img src=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'
```

input:

```
<img src="geo.yahoo.com/b?s=792600534"; height="1" width="1" style="position: absolute;" />
```

output:

```
https://geo.yahoo.com/b?s=792600534
```

Comment: input: <img src="https://geo.yahoo.com/b?s=792600534" height="1" width="1" style="position: absolute;" />

Comment: Could you ask a more specific question? What part of it is confusing to you? If you understand the basics of `sed` and regular expressions, it should be very straightforward.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to escape `"` in the regular expression.

Comment: Either your input or output has a typo as https:// is not in one but is in the other

Answer (score 0):

This part is the regular expression to match with a capturing group Later referred as `\1` (first capturing group). It extracting the value of the `src` attribute.

```
First part if the regex -> <img src=\"
capturing group         -> \([^"]*\)
rest of the regex       -> .*
```

The expression inside the square brackets could be read as: "anything not a double quote".

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a scripting language.  Its `s` command performs substitutions using regular expressions.  The syntax is `s/regex/replacement/flags`.  In your example, you have the regex

```
<img src=\"\([^"]*\).*
```

and the replacement

```
\1
```

and the flags

```
g
```

The regex is apparently attempting to parse HTML, which deserves you a place in a warm location where a friendly gentleman with a pitchfork helps you with motivational issues.  Far, far away, God reluctantly ends the life of a fluffy kitten.

The regular expression contains a capturing group, which is simply the text which matched between the parentheses.  The replacement `\1` refers back to this captured text.  So in brief, you are taking away the parts which matched *around* this captured string.

```
s/foo\(bar\)baz/\1/
```

replaces `foobarbaz` with just `baz`, retrieving the "baz" part from whatever matched, rather than hard-coding a replacement string.

The regular expression `.*` matches any character any number of times; the regular expression engine will prefer the longest, leftmost possible match.

The regular expression `[^"]*` matches a single character which is not (newline or) `"` and the `*` again says to match as many times as possible. So `"\([^"]*\)"` finds a double-quoted string, and captures its contents; the negated `"` prevents the regular expression from matching past the closing quote when matching as many characters as possible. (As noted in comments, the backslash before the first `"` is unnecessary, but basically harmless. It just tells us that whoever wrote this isn't a regex wizard.)

However, your example just implicitly includes the closing quote in the `.*` match which will simply match everything from the closing quote through to the end of the line.

The `g` flag says to repeat the substitution command as many times as possible; so if an input line contains multiple matches, all of them will be replaced. (Without the `g` flag, `sed` will just replace the first match it finds on a line.)  But since you just removed the rest of the line, the flag isn't actually useful here; there can only ever be a single match.

The gentleman with the pitchfork doesn't want me to tell you this, but this code is not suitable for a general-purpose script.  There is no guarantee that the `src` attribute of the `img` element will be immediately adjacent to the `img` opening tag with just a single space in between; HTML allows arbitrary spacing (including a line wrap) and you can have other attributes like `id` or `alt` or `title` which could go before or after the `src` attribute.  The proper solution is to use a HTML parser to extract the `src` attributes of `img` tags with proper understanding of the surrounding syntax.

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/img" -m "@src" -v '.' -n
```

... though the stray semicolon after the `src` attribute is a HTML syntax violation; is it really there in your input?

(`xmlstarlet` command line shamelessly adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3174307/874188)